# Ubuntu software error "Error opening directory "/usr/share/appdata": No such file or directory"

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I'm new to Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to install or deinstall using Ubuntu Software I get this message:

> Sorry, something went wrong: Error opening directory "/usr/share/appdata": No such file or directory.

How can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: popup message]

Comment: You can find here the ticket on this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1888219

Answer (score 91):

Ran into the same issue today, ending the process and re-opening it resolved it for me.

Steps to reproduce what I did:

- Open System Monitor and search for `snap-store`
- Select the `snap-store` process and hit End Process
- Re-open Ubuntu Software

On the technical side of things this looks like a minor permissions issue, not much to worry about.

Comment: It Works!! Very Thanks!

Comment: thank you, yes it seems like permissions issue

Comment: You can also run `killall snap-store` from the Terminal for the same effect, if you don't have System Monitor

Comment: Works ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I need to do this every single time I use the store; is there a definite solution to solve the permission issues? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't kill the snap-store process so I just restarted my computer to clear the error.

Comment: Using system monitor to End Process took a moment and a force quit confirmation. Use the "End Process" button at the bottom of the window, rather than the options presented when right clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Get the pid and kill it:

```
$ ps -aux | grep snap-store

user1 1591 0.0 0.8 1338376 138668 ?  Sl Feb01 3:04 /snap/snap-store/467/usr/bin/snap-store --gapplication-service

$ kill -9 1591
```

Reopen ubuntu software